# Chrome extension: Cannot run code in chrome.tabs.executeScript in context of the page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created an extension for Google Chrome with this background script `background.js`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"document.body.style.background='red !important';"}); // doesn't work
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"alert('hello');"}); // runs alert
});
```

I want to run `document.body.style.background='red !important';` in the context of the web page.
How can I do it?

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Test",
  "browser_action": { "default_icon": "icon.png" },
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "*://*/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain and straight. Add `https://*/*` to permissions.

Comment: Thanks, I've just fixed it. I slightly changed question.

Answer (score 1):

background actually expects everything, if you want to change the color use backgroundColor and need not give !important as you are injecting after everything is loaded.

So the below change may work. Please try that.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='red';"});
```